# Recover .storyboard file from Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I'm an idiot and started coding an app without any backups and the inevitable happened. I accidently deleted the Storyboard file from the app package. It doesn't show up in trash, I clicked to delete the file and not just the references too.

I am currently running a search using MacKeeper 2012 to try and recover the file but i'm not holding my breath for this.

The thing that gives me hope of not having to recreate the storyboard file again is that when I compile and run the application in the simulator it runs as if the storyboard file is still there. Is there any way of getting this file back through Xcode?

Comment: Horray for another horror story in support of using *Time Machine* and/or a source code repository like Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you are using version control you can revert the file and if you don't use version control instead use snapshots. You could look over there.

Hope it helps you.